# extract tweets with some special keywords from twitter using tweepy in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

here is my code..i want to extract tweets from twitter with some keywords....my code dont give any errors but i am not getting the output file generated...please help me........

```
import re
import csv
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
#TextBlob perform simple natural language processing tasks.
from textblob import TextBlob



def search():
    #text = e.get() **************************

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ' '
access_token_secret = ' '
# create OAuthHandler object
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# set access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
# create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def get_tweets(query, count = 300):

   # empty list to store parsed tweets
   tweets = []
   target = open("tweets.txt", 'w',encoding="utf-8")
   t1 = open("review.txt", 'w',encoding="utf-8")
   # call twitter api to fetch tweets
   q=str(query)
   a=str(q+" sarcasm")
   b=str(q+" sarcastic")
   c=str(q+" irony")
   fetched_tweets = api.search(a, count = count)+ api.search(b, count = count)+ api.search(c, count = count)
   # parsing tweets one by one
   print(len(fetched_tweets))

   for tweet in fetched_tweets:

       # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
       parsed_tweet = {}
       # saving text of tweet
       parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
       if "http" not in tweet.text:
           line = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", " ", tweet.text)
           target.write(line+"\n")
           t1.write(line+"\n")
   return tweets

   # creating object of TwitterClient Class
   # calling function to get tweets
tweets = get_tweets(query =text, count = 20000)

root.mainloop()
```

From this code i am nor getting the output generated file. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please format your code properly with four leading spaces on each line (select it and then either click the brackets {} or type `strg+k`).

Comment: and I assume you removed the keys and secrets only for posting it here? Or in your local file, too?

Comment: What output you are getting by running this code ? do you get your desired output and the only issue is that you can't be able to save those tweets to a file ?

Comment: when i run the code with python tweet.py in the terminal it comes just like.........~/Desktop/miniproject$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made some slight changes and it was working perfectly for me. Removed or commented some unnecessary statements (like the review file). Changed the open function to io.open since I have python version 2.7. Here is the running code, hope it helps!!

`

```
import re
import io
import csv
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
#TextBlob perform simple natural language processing tasks.
#from textblob import TextBlob


consumer_key = 'sz6x0nvL0ls9wacR64MZu23z4'
consumer_secret = 'ofeGnzduikcHX6iaQMqBCIJ666m6nXAQACIAXMJaFhmC6rjRmT'
access_token = '854004678127910913-PUPfQYxIjpBWjXOgE25kys8kmDJdY0G'
access_token_secret = 'BC2TxbhKXkdkZ91DXofF7GX8p2JNfbpHqhshW1bwQkgxN'
# create OAuthHandler object
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# set access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
# create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
api = tweepy.API(auth)




def get_tweets(query, count = 300):

    # empty list to store parsed tweets
    tweets = []
    target = io.open("mytweets.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    # call twitter api to fetch tweets
    q=str(query)
    a=str(q+" sarcasm")
    b=str(q+" sarcastic")
    c=str(q+" irony")
    fetched_tweets = api.search(a, count = count)+ api.search(b, count = count)+ api.search(c, count = count)
    # parsing tweets one by one
    print(len(fetched_tweets))

    for tweet in fetched_tweets:

        # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
        parsed_tweet = {}
        # saving text of tweet
        parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
        if "http" not in tweet.text:
            line = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", " ", tweet.text)
            target.write(line+"\n")
    return tweets

    # creating object of TwitterClient Class
    # calling function to get tweets
tweets = get_tweets(query ="", count = 20000)
```

`

Comment: thankyou..the above code is working .... now can i get the code to extract sentiment related features from tweets

Comment: You may want to remove your `consumer_secret` and `token_secret`